# Source for KL-divergence of Beta distribution?

Tags: references, beta-distribution, kullback-leibler

This post explains how to derive the Kullback-Leibler divergence between two beta distributions.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257821/kullback-liebler-divergence#comment564291_257821

I understand the logic, but is there a formal source that derives this result? I would like to be able to cite it.

Comment: See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320307003123?casa_token=7xgsjAgG4GwAAAAA:F7SdKs0Ch3w4AUEueTXH9trAx6zL-950u9_8EBsxDn4maW-_KbwYc_IJr8RhWi-pp1veeLWMMWnR

Comment: I found this blog post helpful - [Kullback-Leibler Divergence Between Two Dirichlet (and Beta) Distributions](https://bariskurt.com/kullback-leibler-divergence-between-two-dirichlet-and-beta-distributions/)